# Copy IntPtr BRGA to RGBA byte[] With Marshal.Copy

Tags: c#, marshalling, awesomium, rgba, sfml.net

Im currently copying a byte[] from a BGRA IntPtr Buffer using Marshal.Copy as follows:

```
    private static byte[] getWebViewScreenshotAsBytes(ref WebView myWebView)
    {
        int colorLength = myWebView.Width * myWebView.Height;
        BitmapSurface bmpSurface = (BitmapSurface)myWebView.Surface;

        byte[] bgra = new byte[colorLength * 4];
        Marshal.Copy(bmpSurface.Buffer, bgra, 0, colorLength * 4);

        byte[] rgba = new byte[colorLength * 4];
        for(int i = 0; i < bgra.Length; i += 4)
        {
            rgba[i] = bgra[i + 2];
            rgba[i + 1] = bgra[i + 1];
            rgba[i + 2] = bgra[i];
            rgba[i + 3] = bgra[i + 3];
        }

        return rgba;
    }
```

As you can see I'm then looping through the byte[] four at a time to change the BGRA format to a RGBA format.

**My question is this:**
*Is there any way to switch the bytes into the correct RGBA postion from their BGRA as they're copied from the IntPtr into the manaaged byte[], saving me the looping?*

If there's any context needed on this, I'm getting the buffered image from Awesomium WebView Surfaces (BGRA), and I'm using it in a SFML.NET Texture (RGBA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BitmapSurface` class has a `CopyTo` method that takes a `bool convertToRGBA` parameter:

```
public void CopyTo(
    IntPtr destBuffer,
    int destRowSpan,
    int destDepth,
    bool convertToRGBA,
    bool flipY
)
```

See [API documentation](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/M_Awesomium_Core_BitmapSurface_CopyTo.htm)